# Increasing dilimited string not parsing correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to break up a string coming in '!|!':

```
DECLARE @value varchar(max) = 'A750!|!none!|!none!|!N'
DECLARE @test varchar(max) = Replace(@value, '!|!', '.');

declare @my1 varchar(500) = (SELECT ParseName(@test, 1))
declare @my2 varchar(500) = (SELECT ParseName(@test, 2))
declare @my3 varchar(500) = (SELECT ParseName(@test, 3))
declare @my4 varchar(500) = (SELECT ParseName(@test, 4))
declare @my5 varchar(500) = (SELECT ParseName(@test, 5))
declare @my6 varchar(500) = (SELECT ParseName(@test, 6))
declare @my7 varchar(500) = (SELECT ParseName(@test, 7))

select @my1
select @my2
select @my3
select @my4
select @my5
select @my6
select @my7
```

Results:

[image]

But when I change the string to have another value:

```
DECLARE @value varchar(max) = 'A750!|!none!|!none!|!N!|!Y'
```

All NULLs return:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I get more incoming separated values into variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option

```
Declare @value varchar(max) = 'A750!|!none!|!none!|!N'
Declare @my1 varchar(500) 
Declare @my2 varchar(500) 
Declare @my3 varchar(500) 
Declare @my4 varchar(500) 
Declare @my5 varchar(500) 
Declare @my6 varchar(500) 
Declare @my7 varchar(500) 

Select @my1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
      ,@my2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
      ,@my3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
      ,@my4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
      ,@my5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
      ,@my6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
      ,@my7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@value,'!|!','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A
```

Answer (score 2):

[Parsename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) is supposed to be used for splitting the 4-part object name, not for generic string splitting -- and your script would totally break if the data contains `.`.

Just use a generic splitting function instead, for example [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden

Comment: Plus1 - my 1st thought as well.  Everyone should have a good splitter